# Prevent windows application from auto-resize

Tags: oracle, window, oracleforms, autoresize

I have problem with my application resizing automatically (**not** during drag the window to edge).
I often divide my screen on two halves (on one half I have oracle forms application and on the second half I have oracle forms designer). But when I go to another form inside my Oracle forms application then Oracle Forms Application automatically resizes to full-screen mode and hides the second half of screen with my Oracle Forms Designer.

I would like to prevent Oracle Forms Application from auto-resize. This is well-known problem in my company. Auto full-screen is needed in application for client but not for us (programmers) while debugging.
Code invoking maximizing:

```
Set_Window_Property('FORM_NAME',WINDOW_STATE,MAXIMIZE);
```

P.S. Sorry, I haven't idea where to qualify my question.
I tried install: Desktops EULA (multi desktops), PersistentWindows (edit properties of window) but none of it satisfied me because it didn't prevent oracle app from take all space on screen.

Any solution (I'd appreciate general solution - not linked with oracle forms)?

Comment: In which way do you go to another form inside your Oracle forms application's runtime(such as by clicking to a button ...etc.) ?

Comment: Clicking a button. Maximizing fires in PRE-FORM.